# Where are the mistakes in my own sqrt() function?

Tags: c, square-root

Learning C for a couple of days, wanted to write a code to find the square root of a number by Newton's method.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int truncate (double num)             //rounds float to integer
{
    if (num < 0) {
            return (num + 0.5);
    }
    else {
        return (num - 0.5);
    }
}

double sqr(double num){              //square function
    return num * num;
}

double sqrt(double number) {         //root function
    double guess, quotient, average;

    guess = 1.0;

    do {
        quotient = number / guess;
        printf("%f\t", quotient);
        average = (guess + quotient) / 2.0;
        printf("%f\n", average);
        guess = average;
    } while ((abs(number - sqr(guess))) > 0.001);

    return guess;
}

int main(){
    float a;

    scanf("%f", a);

    printf("%.2f", sqrt(a));

}
```

What are the mistakes?
Error:
Process returned -1073741819 (0xC0000005)   execution time : 2.371 s

Comment: You're missing a `&`: `scanf("%f",&a);`. Also note that `abs` is for integers, you should replace that with `fabs`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works now.

Comment: Run it in a debugger, step through line by line, examining your variables as you go. That answers about 90% of all questions on this site, which should tell you how important it is to use a debugger. if you don't, stop whatever you are doing and write no more code until you learn how to use the debugger.

Comment: Configure your compiler to show extra warnings, an treat them as errors. The biggest mistake you can make is to work in an unforgiving language like C, but disregard excellent diagnostics in todays compilers. [This is what you should get when you try to compile.](https://godbolt.org/z/0pQqXd)

Comment: @Groo Except... the diagnostic message here is not excellent, but horrible. `format '%f' expects argument of type 'float *', but argument 2 has type 'double' [-Werror=format=]`. Good luck making sense of that as a beginner who passed a `float`. Apparently the message is printed after default argument promotions. Or alternatively, this is a gcc bug. I lean towards the latter.

Comment: Just curious: why does your `truncate` function return a rounded value?

Comment: @Mawg: debugging is dead. Long live SO. :-(

Comment: Lolx!  yup, that's why I come here every day :-)

Comment: Seriously, though, answering questions which ought to have been solved by the debugger & never posted somewhat leads away from the goal of being a repository of knowledge :-(

Comment: @Lundin: it might be confusing to a novice programmer, but many compiler errors are. But, "horrible"? 1) The compiler recognizes this is a "special" function which accepts format specifiers. 2) Compiler then parses the format string and checks whether it matches the list. 3) It all culminates in a compile error, meaning you don't have to detect the error the hard way -- which is in this case, luckily, rather easy. I think it's reasonable for the compiler to perform default argument promotions *before* checking if they will break at runtime. Clang gives the exact same error message.

Comment: @Groo It is not just the default argument promotion, it is the old `%f` versus `%lf` debacle. `printf("%f", my_double);` and `printf("%lf", my_float);` give no warnings at all, except if you compile in C90 mode.

Comment: @Lundin: but a `float` always gets promoted into a `double` with variable arguments, the warning happens because a *pointer* is required. So 1) `double x; scanf("%f", x);` would again say *"need `float*` but got `double`"*, or 2) `double x; scanf("%lf", x);` would say *"need `double*` but got `double`"*, or 3) `double* px; scanf("%lf", px);`" would say *"need `float*` but got `double*`"* because pointers don't get promoted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass a `double` to the function, instead, in main, you're passing a float.

just change `float a;` to `double a;`

Also, in main, you have to write `scanf("%lf",&a);` instead of `scanf("%lf",a);`. That's the only way you'll calculate on the right number you pass your program.